# Robots.txt different from the one in directory

Tags: robots.txt

I can't figure out why Google reads my robots.txt file as `Disallow: /`.

This is what I have in my robots.txt file that is in the main root directory:

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /
```

But if I digit in browser it will show `Disallow: /`: http://revita.hr/robots.txt

I tried everything, submitted the sitemap, added meta robots index, follow into `<head>`, but it's always the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a different robots.txt file if accessing it via HTTPS (→ `Allow`) instead of HTTP (→ `Disallow`).

---

By the way, you don’t need to state

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

because allowing everything is the default. As `Allow` is not part of the original robots.txt specification, you might want to use this instead:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Also note that you should not have a blank line inside a record.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how is possible to have different robots.txt if accessing via https instead of http? I tried and I noticed that, you're right but don't understand why if I have only one robots.txt file that is in the root directory.

Comment: @MaraBarn: If you look at the response headers, the HTTP robots.txt is served by a nginx server, while the HTTPS robots.txt is served by an Apache server. The HTTP one was last modified in November 2014, and is cached until February 2017. -- So it seems you run two servers somehow? And the HTTP server did cache it for a long time?